# How to reformat labels chartisan

Tags: laravel

### Heading

```
<script>
    const chart = new Chartisan({
        el: '#chart',
        url: "@chart('sample_chart')",
        hooks: new ChartisanHooks() //labels format
            .datasets([{type: 'line', fill: false}, 'bar'])
            .legend()
            .colors()
            .tooltip()
            .title('Sample Chart'),
    });
</script>
</body>
```

How can format labels to be vertical in Laravel chartisan? I suppose that this part of the code has to change, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

```
  const chart = new Chartisan({
  el: '#chart',
  url: "@chart('sample_chart')",
  hooks: new ChartisanHooks()
    .colors()
    .responsive()
    .beginAtZero()
    .legend({ position: 'bottom' })
    .datasets([{ type: 'line', fill: true }])
    .custom(function ({ data, merge, server }) {
      data.options.scales.yAxes = [{
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '$' + value;
          }
        }
      }]

      return data
    })
})
```

For more info visit this link:https://github.com/Chartisan/Chartisan/issues/7

Comment: I had already seen that, but no.